# The sum of two identical vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Does the sum of two identical vector spaces, with the same dimension and basis, produces a greater vector space? or is it like in set theory, that if the two groups are the same then, the result is the same also?

Comment: can you please specify what is "vector spaces being identical", Do you mean having same dimension with same base field?? What is your notion of sum??

Comment: Depends what you mean by sum!

Comment: what are the options for ''summing''?

Comment: Basically, If you have these two spaces as subspaces of some bigger space, then you can define sum of these two spaces to be sum restricted to subspace. Another thing is if you have two vector spaces of same dimensions and same basis, you are just adding two elements of same space, then by very definition of vector space, their sum should be with in the space. So there is no point of getting bigger space. Do you really mean same basis???

Comment: lets suppose we have two vector subspaces with the same basis and dimension, and we add them up ,if it is at all possible. Do we get a larger subspace then?

Comment: well actually they do since they still have the same basis...

Comment: i have already mentioned that if you have same basis, you are going to get same space... I would rephrase my comment as :

If you have two spaces with same dimension, seem to be same at first sight (but they are different when seen as subspaces of a bigger space ) then the answer would be different. I would suggest you to look for the answer by Mr.Avitus below... I see both $\mathbb{R}$ in first co ordinate and second coordinate as same... but, they have different basis when considered as subspaces... and that makes the difference and we get a bigger space.... So, "Basis" plays a major role...

Comment: Thanks...that pretty much clarifies it..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider two copies of $\mathbb R^2$, seen as vector spaces over $\mathbb R$. Then

$$\mathbb R\oplus \mathbb R=\mathbb R^2,$$

where the vector space on the r.h.s. is $2$-dimensional (again, over $\mathbb R$). Geometrically, you started with the $x$ and $y$-axis (i.e. the $2$ copies of $\mathbb R$) and you arrived, through the direct sum, to the real plane. A basis of the latter is given by $(1,0), (0,1)$, where $1$ denotes a basis in the corresponding copy of $\mathbb R$.

In summary, to answer to your question, the direct sum does not behave like "in set theory, that if the two groups are the same then, the result is the same also".

**EDIT** I used "sum" as direct sum and I considered as "same" the property of having the same dimension (for vector spaces). If the OP specified a bit more these concepts, I would modify the answer accordingly.